# Catboost Classifer early_stopping_rounds doesn't seem to work (python)

Tags: python, catboost

Will probably spelunk more into the Catboost implementation to figure out what's going on, but wanted to check in with the SO community first to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid before I waste my time. I was trying to test out Catboost's early_stopping rounds to speed up parameter search, and was surprised to see that even when I raised up learning rates to stupidly high values the model still fit through all iterations!

Asking for just a quick confirmation that my code looks ok/if anyone's had a similar experience working with Catboost. I've confirmed here that the loss value here changes sporadically as expected, but the fitting continues for the 10 iterations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest self-answer, but leaving it up here since this wasn't clear to me. Early stopping rounds **ONLY** works if you have eval_set specified. The more you know.

[image]